# SQL Server not connecting via IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I am getting the following error when I deploy my application to `IIS`:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)]

What is interesting about this is that it is happening at the folder level. I have the same application, running on the same `IIS` server and it connects to the `SQL server` without issue - and the complied code is the same. The only difference is the folder that has the content. I am leaning towards a permission issue - but I did not change any of those.

Comment: Are the `web.config` files same?

Comment: Name of folder? Also, do you have your database access code at different places.

Comment: are you able to ping sqlserver from the server where you deployed IIS

Comment: @TheGameiswar he said the same application is connected in the same server. so it is able to ping it.

Comment: The config files are the same. I have a DEV folder and Stage Folder. The dev folder is having the issue, I moved the content from stage to dev and get the same error.

Comment: @JimPendarvis are connectionstrings of both applications identical ? U confirmed to check for any typo in them ?

Comment: It may be because your 'dev' folder do not have permission. go to 'dev' folder properties. Then in security tab give full control permission to iis.